# select a column where the column name is retrieved from a query

Tags: sql, mysql, oracle

I'm looking for a elegant way to select a column from table A where as the column name is retrieved from a query on table B.

A query on table B results in `'col01'`
The Table A has several columns named `'col01','col02','col03',...`

Final query should be for result

```
result from B | effective SQL query
 'col01'      |  SELECT col01 FROM A
 'col02'      |  SELECT col02 FROM A
```

I'm looking for pure SQL solution with no scripting. It should run with Oracle and/or MySQL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm looking for pure SQL solution with no scripting.

This is not possible. You have to create the statements dynamically.

Comment: I sort of thought it's kind of impossible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In a *very* simple case you can just about do it with a `CASE` statement, but this is unlikely to be of much use in the real world:

```
with a as (
    select 'col_01_val_01' as col_01, 'col_02_val_01' as col_02,
        'col_03_val_01' as col_03 from dual
    union select 'col_01_val_02' as col_01, 'col_02_val_02' as col_02,
        'col_03_val_02' as col_03 from dual
    union select 'col_01_val_03' as col_01, 'col_02_val_03' as col_02,
        'col_03_val_03' as col_03 from dual),
b as (
    select 1 parm, 'col_01' value from dual
    union select 2 parm, 'col_02' value from dual
    union select 3 parm, 'col_03' value from dual)
select b.value as result_from_b,
    case b.value
        when 'col_01' then col_01
        when 'col_02' then col_02
        when 'col_03' then col_03 end as result_from_a
from a, b
where b.parm = 1;

RESULT_FROM_B RESULT_FROM_A
------------- -------------
col_01        col_01_val_01
col_01        col_01_val_02
col_01        col_01_val_03
```

The columns have to be the same type (or at least expressible as such in the case), and `b` can only return one row... And it isn't very pretty of course. For anything more complicated you need dynamic SQL as @a_horse_with_no_name has already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done within a stored routine in MySQL.  I don't know about Oracle as I haven't used it.  You can find out more about MySQL stored procedures [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedprocedures.pdf) (the 2nd link is a pretty good PDF which walks you through some simple examples).

Comment: The requirement was *a solution with no scripting* so that rules out stored procedures.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Very true. However, I took that to mean no external (to the DB) scripting, which left stored routines as the only option. With no scripting at all, then of course you are correct.